# NP-completeness and reducibility

Tags: algorithm, proof, reduction, np-complete, np

I'm fairly new to this website so I apologize if this question is in the wrong section.  I am taking an algorithm analysis class and am stuck on one of my homework problems and would appreciate it if I could receive some guidance.

The problem I'm stuck on is proving that the empty language and {0, 1}* are the only languages in P that are not complete for P with respect to polynomial-time reductions (problem 34.3-6 in CLRS 3rd edition).  The first part of the problem seems fairly straightforward enough (proving the empty language criteria).  However, I'm not sure where to even begin when I have to prove the criteria for {0, 1}*.  I'm NOT looking for the answer, however I would appreciate some guidance on how I can begin to think about this problem.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably more on-topic at programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I believe the [Computer Science stack exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) is actually more suited for this type of question.

Comment: Perhaps the fact that the empty language and {0, 1}* are complementary should help.

Comment: The title of the question mentions NP-completeness while the question itself asks about P-completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of P Completeness with regards to polynomial time reduction is, a problem L is P-Complete if:

1. L is in P
2. There is a polynomial time reduction from each problem in P to L.

For `L = {}`, given a problem `X` such that `X!= {}`, you need to find a reduction `p` such for each instance of `X` (let it be `x`), `p(x)` is in `L` if and only if `x` is in `X`.

Assume there is such `p`. However, since `X != {}`, there is some `x` such that `x` is in `X`, and `p(x)` cannot be in `L`, since `L` is empty. Contradiction for the existence of such `p`.

Repeat similarly for `L={0,1}*` with any language `X != {0,1}*`, and `x` is not in `X`.